# Custom PDO Error try/catch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling

Currently when there is an error with my SQL it throws the traditional error that looks like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax...|
```

I know I can achieve what I want by wrapping every SQL routine in a try/catch block but this seems a little long winded:

```
class ProductsModel extends Model {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

 public function setName($name, $productId)
  {
    $SQL = 'UPDATE products SET name = ? WHERE id = ?';
    try{
    $r = $this->db->prepare($SQL);
    $r->execute(array($name, $productId));
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Error!';
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to have this done automatically for all SQL queries made?

Comment: Why is the client aware of the fact it's SQL queries happening? What are you _really_ trying to convey to the client? If you'd like to indicate a failure return a 500 server error status code - use status codes for this the client should not be aware of server internals. Moreover, it's extremely bad practice to catch and suppress all errors like that. Instead, if they're exceptional handle them in the code that calls setName or alternatively define the contract in a way that conveys it failing is a legitimate outcome (have it return a boolean) for example. Blind suppression is always bad.

Comment: Dude, you accepted the answer that contradicts with your question. -1

Comment: @YourCommonSense I would accept your answer as it is more educational, but it has been locked :/

Comment: Better accept Wayne's one - he's been the first with direct and exact answer to your question - "how to do whatever exception handling in one place" - exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is, and no, you shouldn't do it.

What you **should** do, is ***not*** to catch it inside the function, and instead, wrap the method call inside of the higher level with the catch block. i.e.:

```
try {
    $productsModel->setName("name", 42);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    //Do something, 500 error code, whatever
}
```

That's because, **only when you try to access the database you know what you want to do in case it fails**.

This:

- Leaves your method cleaner, no error handling needed inside of the method.
- Gives you flexibility. At some point you may want to throw a 500 error if it fails, at another, you may want to return a JSON object to an AJAX call.

Comment: I will consider it, sounds good to me, but could someone explain the down vote as I would like to know why you disagree?

Comment: +1 from me too. Solutions designed to be "one size fits all" usually make too many assumptions, and you end up having to provide ways to override the global solution anyway.

Comment: @imperium2335 the down-vote probably stems from inexperience. Your objects in your code convey ways of interaction and contracts you make. If your `setName` silently fails it breaches its contract (setting the name). It must either indicate that the situation is exceptional (via throwing) or convey it's a possible outcome (by becoming `trySetName` for example and returning true on success and false on failure.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum this answer is actually a shame.

Comment: @YourCommonSense please do elaborate. We're all here to learn. If there is something I'm not getting I want to know.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I sent you an email, hopefully you won't mind clarifying there since you feel this environment is hostile or unconstructive.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I would like to discuss this with you over chat, Colonel. Invite me to a private chat if you want, or come to the PHP room if that's OK with you.

Answer (score 4):

You can setup an [exception handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

```
<?php
function exception_handler($exception) {
  echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception');
echo "Not Executed\n";
?>
```

It will catch all Exception types, not just PDOExceptions. If you want to specifically handle all PDOExceptions, you can check like so:

```
function exception_handler($exception) {
   if ($exception instanceof PDOException) {
       echo 'This is a PDOException';
   }
}
```

Comment: That is a horrible idea.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Exception handlers are a common thing. Is it not better to show a friendly "Something went wrong" page to the user?

Comment: Not, it most certainly is not. An exception handler like that allows you to do things you shouldn't be doing. A method throws an Exception for a reason, you are expected to be a good developer and catch it, otherwise, a fatal error is appropriate. Clean up your own mess, and don't rely on magic to do it for you.

Comment: @WayneWhitty It could be quite flexible, the main reason I am wanting to do this is because I want to return friendlier errors via AJAX back to the user as something like {"error": "Something"}

Comment: @MadaraUchiha "A method throws an Exception for a reason, you are expected to be a good developer and catch it"... Um, that's referred to as Pokemon exception handling simply because it is a case of "gotta catch them all". You do NOT have to catch every exception.

Comment: @imperium2335 actually you don't. AJAX calls always aware of the HTTP status codes, and all you need on a cliient side is to check for 500 and say "something went wrong".

Comment: @WayneWhitty: Yes, you absolutely do have to catch every exception. If you rely on magic to catch your exceptions, maintaining it in the future would be hard. Teaching your code to a junior developer would be twice as hard.

Comment: It isn't magic. It is an exception handler. You seem to be forgetting the fact that you can log exceptions.

Comment: It's the very definition of magic, if you by any chance miss the fact that you called for `set_exception_handler()` you have no idea what's going on, and if you fail to log or give sufficient alert, you'll miss the exception altogether. I will repeat myself again, this is a **horrible** idea.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Why would you setup an exception handler and then fail to log or throw a 500? Log, throw a 500 or even send off an alert email if it tickles your fancy.

Comment: Characterizing this as "magic" doesn't mean we don't understand how it works, it means it's trying to use **one solution** to handle all cases, which doesn't work. For example, look at the history of PHP's "magic quotes" feature, which eventually became deprecated. Trying to force one solution to handle all cases *reduces* flexibility -- it does not improve flexibility.

Comment: @BillKarwin Worth noting that if you catch the exception, it'll never reach set_exception_handler.

Comment: @BillKarwin it still bugs me so much that I cant help it but ask: do you *really* think that having a mere error/exception handler is some sort of "magic" and shouldn't be implemented at all?

Comment: @WayneWhitty, right, that would be handling an exception on a case by case basis -- at least some of the time. That's fine. The undesirable "magic" code design would be writing one exception handler and expect it to handle *all* cases. Creating an exception handler which catches *many* cases (as a default when you don't catch it yourself) is also fine.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I didn't say  never to create exception handlers. But using one exception handler to handle all cases (that is, with *no* `try...catch` blocks in your code to handle special cases) is an oversimplified solution.

Comment: @BillKarwin Oversimplified or not - but it's must have anyway, because you cannot foresee all the probable errors and create dedicated handler for all of them. So, please, don't call this important mechanism "magic", "undesirable" or discourage it whatever else way.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I agree it's bad practice to allow exceptions to not be handled by *anything*, which just shows your user an ugly white screen with exception error messages. So an exception handler is desirable, if only to present a screen that is more friendly, and appears to be part of the same web app. I do not discourage exception handlers -- I discourage using exception handlers as an excuse to avoid handling specific exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Implement your own class PDO class:

```
class MYPDO extends PDO {
  public function query() {
    try {
      call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::query'), func_get_args());
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Error!';
    }
  }
}

$db = new MYPDO(...);
$db->query(...);
```

Comment: That is a horrible idea.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I agree this is a bad idea. If you want to suppress all exceptions, then just don't configure PDO to throw exceptions. But it's better to use exceptions and catch them more appropriately, which potentially means doing something different on a case by case basis throughout your app.

Comment: If you think this is horrible does not mean it is horrible. You will get all you wanted. Only queries, only PDOException. It's not a good practice, I agree, but take a look on your question ;)

Comment: I disagree: if someone is asking something and answering what this person ask end the situation in creating something horrible someone should say it and explain why. A lot of people ask how to do something they think is the way to do, not the initial reason why the person was thinking it was a good way.

Comment: If you need to catch only one specific exception (PDOException) in only one method (PDO::query) this is one logical way to achieve.

Comment: May I ask you one simple question?